# Display saved data in dropdown list - html select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a static dropdown list in a form as below:

```
<select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
<option value="">Please select a Brand</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
<option value="Sony">Sony</option>
</select>
```

When User choose a brand, let say: Apple and Submit the form. The value "Apple" will be saved in mysql database. I have option for user to edit their form after submitting it.

When user edits the form, I know how to retrieve data from mysql and echo it out but how to make this option which contains value "Apple" as selected so that this value "Apple" will be shown up as default in stead of "Please select a brand"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the variable from your database holding this value is `$brand` then you could do something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
   <option value="">Please select a Brand</option>
   <option value='Apple' <?php echo $brand=='Apple'?'selected':''; ?>>Apple</option>
   <option value='Samsung' <?php echo $brand=='Samsung'?'selected':''; ?>>Samsung</option>
   <option value='Sony' <?php echo $brand=='Sony'?'selected':''; ?>>Sony</option>
</select>
```

Of course this could be done by a loop if you could get all your brands in one query. Perhaps something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
<?php
 $brands_array=array("Apple","Samsung","Sony"); // could come from DB
  foreach($brands_array as $b) {
   echo '<option value="',$b,'"',( $brand==$b ?' selected="selected"':'').'>',$b,'</option>';
  }
?>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Credits to Ismael Miguel for his valuable comments and suggestions

Comment: If you are going to do with PHP, use an array with all the brands. Also, your code would give tons of syntax errors since you have mixed quotes on the `$brand=='<brand>"` check.

Comment: This is what I suggested with the brands being in a loop. I will update the answer. You are right about the quotes. Typo.

Comment: Your update looks great, but avoid using variables with capitals. In PHP, variables with capitals are considered 'system' variables. Also, notice that `$brand=='$b'` will *always* be `False` since you don't have the brand `$b` on your array. You want `$brand=="$b"` or **better** yet `$brand==$b`. You also have a small typo: you have 'perhas' instead of 'perhaps'.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks for your comments. The capitals are just to highlight it. No other reason. I would expect it to come from DB. Also `'$b'` you are spot on!

Comment: As a micro-optimization and improvement on readability (hence a new comment), don't use these quotes: `""`. Rewrite your echo as `echo '<option value="',$b,'"',( $brand==$b ?' selected="selected"':'').'>',$b,'</option>';`. Echo can have multiple arguments, and this is a small bit faster, but also a lot easier to read.

Comment: Now you have 2 typos in 1: `foreach($brandsas $b)` should be `foreach($brands_array as $b)`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel clicked submit too soon :)

Comment: Don't worry, your code looks great now. I don't know if you noticed but I've changed the `selected` to `selected="selected"`. This is due to the fact that XHTML doesn't support empty properties (like `selected`). It's a nice thing to add there. You already got my upvote, now you need more upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the "Selected" parameter of your option.

Example :

```
<option value="Apple" selected>Apple</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just connect it to mysql and check which value he checked and then just show selected in option.Use the code below for html

```
<select class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand">
<option value="">Please select a Brand</option>
<option value="Apple" selected>Apple</option>
<option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
<option value="Sony">Sony</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jkrryuhx/

In this example apple will be selected to default

Hope this helps you